# Circular timer/clock in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, flash, time, clock

I am looking for a flash clock online which displays in milliseconds. I need it to be circular style (not digital) and never stop (unless page is refreshed).

Anyone know know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/clock.ht](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/clock.htm)

It also provides a nice walk-through of how to build it, so it should be easy to modify if you feel up to it.

Comment: This is a good one, but it doesn't actually display the milliseconds.

Comment: So do you want a clock with a second and minute hand, but also a digital millisecond display?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Images and CSS3 [`transform:rotate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for doing this.

You can also use [jQuery `rotate()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Rotate) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good flash alternative.

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/flash-clock-analo/

It shows not only the coding required, but help with the interface. It also provides a working sample.

Hope this helps.